# Getline from the string (not from stringstream)

Tags: c++, string, getline, std

Let's say I have a std::string "55|6999|dkfdfd|". It cointains 3 parts (each is followed by |). Currently I put the string to stringstream and I use getline to recover them. However I wonder if there is a simpler solution which doesn't require streams. I just need an easy way to getline from that string using '|' as delim, as I think streams are overkill for it and I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If boost is permitted then [`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp163440592) would be an option. It can be used to populate a `std::vector<std::string>`, which would contain the *fields* extracted from input based on specified delimiter(s):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using std::vector;
using std::string;

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
using boost::split;
using boost::is_any_of;

vector<string> fields;
split(fields, "55|6999|dkfdfd|", is_any_of("|"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::strtok` instead:

```
char *token = std::strtok(<yourstring>, "|");
```

< yourstring > has to be of type `char*` though; and then use `NULL` for the ones after that, `std::strtok` keeps track of the previously used string.

```
token = std::strtok(NULL, "|");
```

Comment: @user1873947, note `strtok` modifies the input so using a string literal would be illegal for example.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is called "tokenizing" a string. That would be generally your best bet. As for how to do it, see "[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)"

Comment: boost::tokenizer seems great.